# Efficiently delete documents from ElasticSearch? Is there a paginated way of deleting documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to refresh some data based on some parameters. After that I have to delete the older data based on refresh timestamp and other fields.
The index has almost 1000000 documents which are added and then older ones deleted.
Is there a paginated way of deleting older documents?

Comment: this is a horribly inefficient way of approaching this problem. I would suggest it's more effective in the longer term to rethink your problem scope

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. We can do it by using DeleteByQuery. We have the option of setting the size.

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation depends on the programming language used, but the general approach would be to use Elasticsearch's Scroll and Bulk APIs.

Use scroll to efficiently retrieve all the documents matching the query (documents to delete) and for each set of results returned by the Scroll API, build and execute a bulk request to delete multiple documents.

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html

[2] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html